# Keras sequential model results not reproducible with wildly inconsistent results on same dataset and parameters optimized using Optuna

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, optuna

I am running a Keras sequential model as a regressor with tensorflow backend. I am using Optuna to optimize it's hyper-paramters and reducing the rmse in the Optuna optimizer.
However, when I re-create the Keras model with the best parameters from Optuna and use the same dataset for re-fitting and predicting as the one used in the Optuna objective function, I get wildly inconsistent results.

I'm aware that neural nets are stochastic in nature with an element of randomness. In order to make it deterministic I tried setting the seeds for both numpy and tensorflow in the following manner at beginning of my script, but it doesn't work,

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
import tensorflow
tensorflow.random.set_seed(2)
```

Following is my code and the output-

```
def create_model(trial):   
    n_layers = trial.suggest_int("layers_number", 4,  8)#4
    model = keras.Sequential()
    for i in range(n_layers):
        num_hidden = trial.suggest_int("n_units_l_{}".format(i), 10, 16)
        activation = trial.suggest_categorical('activation_l_{}'.format(i), ['linear'])#, 'relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh', 'elu'
        model.add(layers.Dense(num_hidden, activation=activation, kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))
        dropout = trial.suggest_uniform("dropout_l_{}".format(i), 0.1, 0.4)
        model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))

    lr = trial.suggest_loguniform("lr", 1e-5, 1e-1)

    model.compile(
        loss='mean_squared_error',
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr),
        metrics=['mse']
    )

    return model
```

```
def objective(trial):
    keras.backend.clear_session()
    model = create_model(trial)
    
    epochs = trial.suggest_int("epochs", 3, 4)#50
    batch = trial.suggest_int("batch", 1, 2)
    
    model.fit(
        X_train.values,
        y_train.values, 
        batch_size=batch, 
        epochs=epochs, 
        verbose=0,
        shuffle=False
    )
    y_pred_test = model.predict(X_test)
    test_copy['pred_scaled'] = y_pred_test
    rmse = inverse_transform(test_copy, y_pred_test, df_copy) #inverse transforms the transformed target and calculates rmse

    return rmse
```

```
study = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize')
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=2)
```

Output- best trial screenshot
[image]

RMSE of best trial is 110.90926282554379

Refitting and predicting using best params.

```
def KerasRegressor(parameters):
    print(parameters)
    model = keras.Sequential()
    layers_number = int(parameters['layers_number'])

    for i in range(layers_number):
        model.add(layers.Dense(int(parameters['n_units_l_' + str(i)]), activation=parameters['activation_l_' + str(i)], kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))
        model.add(layers.Dropout(int(parameters['dropout_l_' + str(i)])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(
        loss='mean_squared_error',
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=float(parameters['lr'])),
        metrics=['mse'])
        
    return model
```

```
params = study.best_trial.params
epochs = params['epochs']
batch = params['batch']
del params['epochs']
del params['batch']

seed(1)
tensorflow.random.set_seed(2)
model = KerasRegressor(params)
model.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch, shuffle=False)

y_pred_test = model.predict(X_test)
test_copy['pred_scaled'] = y_pred_test
rmse = inverse_transform(test_copy, y_pred_test, df_copy)#inverse transforms the transformed target and calculates rmse
print(rmse)
```

New rmse on same dataset as used in Optuna objective function with best hyperparameters-
[image]

New rmse - 227892.23560327655

Small differences in rmse are acceptable but not this large a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have a different approach. I save the model to a file every time optuna finds the best metric. During prediction I just load the model file to predict the test.

If you really want to debug, have a method to find the randomness in your system like fix seed (you did that), fit same data and ordering, use same layers etc. use same param then test it. Run again - fix seed, fit ..., test it. Are the 2 tests results the same? Run multiple test, are the tests the same.

Comment: I think I can go ahead with this possible work-around for now. And as for the debugging by running multiple tests, I did try that, and each time I get completely different result with no correlation to the previous ones whatsoever. Thanks!